# Ubuntu freezes from online forms

Tags: 16.04, crash

I have Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) installed on a laptop from 2014 with 8GB of memory and a quad-core processor (Intel Pentium N3530). Once it a while, it freezes completely (I can't even move the mouse) and I must restart it.

I've recently noticed that it's related to how many tabs I have in Chrome − programs without Internet resources don't seem to impact it. The freezing is especially prone to happening when my changes to a form are being synchronised, eg in Google Docs or Quora. It also seems more impacted by tabs with frequent updates like Facebook.

Is this a problem with my network card or with my memory? I sometimes have system monitor open and the memory might only be at 50% sometimes when the freezing occurs. Sometimes I lose Internet connection while still connected to the network. I'm not sure where to dive deeper − which logs are relevant etc? What would I see there anyway?

I heard about memtest but when running it, the results were going fine until my computer inevitably froze.

I used to have an earlier version of Ubuntu and had hoped that the freezing would stop in 16.04, but I guess not.

Some diagnostics:

```
kokociel@kokociel-Q2550M:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        2.4G        3.8G        463M        1.5G        4.5G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G
kokociel@kokociel-Q2550M:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda3                               partition   8264700 0   -1
```

Comment: Show me `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Edit that output into your question, not the comments. Why couldn't you get memtest to run?

Comment: thanks for the tip; I couldn't recall what was wrong with memtest before − it was just that it never finished before the freezing

Comment: Some Intel CPUs are buggy. I suggest installing `intel-microcode` and upgrading to the 4.10 kernel by `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04`. That fixes the issue in many cases.

Comment: `free -h` and `swapon -s` look fine. Please see my answer for a fix for your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6 − it turns out I already had intel-microcode, but I updated my kernel. I did this in addition to heynnema's answer and it seems all good now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an Intel "Bay Trail" processor that has a bug. The fix is simple.

In `terminal`...

We edit a startup parameter in GRUB with:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

Then:

```
sudo update-grub

reboot
```

Problem fixed!

Comment: I've been using it for ~2½ hours now and it hasn't crashed − thank you!! :)

Comment: @kokociel Power consumption and heating will increase with this setting, but it works.